# Gesture OnFling not called in ListView in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am implementing swipe gesture for a StackLayout(Listview Inside this StackLayout) using CustomRenderer in Xamarin forms. Works perfectly in iOS, but does not work in Android in the listview section.

Swipe works outside the Listview but not work in Listview. I want Gesture OnFling to be fired on swiping the anywhere on the page.

I refered to the link

> https://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

**Here is my code:
Xaml.cs**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SwipeApp1"
             x:Class="SwipeApp1.MainPage">


    <local:FancyStackLayout BackgroundColor="Pink">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowSpacing>0</Grid.RowSpacing>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           TextColor="Blue"/>
            <ListView x:Name="lstContatos" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding userId}"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding title}"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding body}"></Label>

                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </local:FancyLabel>


</ContentPage>
```

CustomRenderer.cs in Droid Project

```
  using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SwipeApp1;
using SwipeApp1.Droid;
using Android.Views;
//[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientStackLayout), 
typeof(GradientStackLayoutRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(FancyStackLayout), 
typeof(FancyAndroidLabelRenderer))]

namespace SwipeApp1.Droid
{
    public class FancyAndroidLabelRenderer : 
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
    {
        private readonly FancyGestureListener _listener;
        private readonly GestureDetector _detector;

        public FancyAndroidLabelRenderer ()
        {
            _listener = new FancyGestureListener ();
            _detector = new GestureDetector (_listener);

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged 
(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.NewElement == null) {
                this.GenericMotion -= HandleGenericMotion;
                this.Touch -= HandleTouch;
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null) {
                this.GenericMotion += HandleGenericMotion;
                this.Touch += HandleTouch;
            }
        }

        void HandleTouch (object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            _detector.OnTouchEvent (e.Event);
        }

        void HandleGenericMotion (object sender, GenericMotionEventArgs e)
        {
            _detector.OnTouchEvent (e.Event);
        }
    }
}
```

GestureListner.cs

```
using Android.Views;
using System;

namespace SwipeApp1.Droid
{
    public class FancyGestureListener : 
GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {

        public override bool OnContextClick(MotionEvent e)
        {
            return base.OnContextClick(e);
        }

        public override void OnLongPress (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnLongPress");
            base.OnLongPress (e);
        }

        public override bool OnDoubleTap (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnDoubleTap");
            return base.OnDoubleTap (e);
        }

        public override bool OnDoubleTapEvent (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnDoubleTapEvent");
            return base.OnDoubleTapEvent (e);
        }

        public override bool OnSingleTapUp (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnSingleTapUp");
            return base.OnSingleTapUp (e);
        }

        public override bool OnDown (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnDown");
            return base.OnDown (e);
        }

        private static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
        public override bool OnFling (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float 
velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine ("OnFling");
            //return base.OnFling (e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                float diffY = e2.GetY() - e1.GetY();
                float diffX = e2.GetX() - e1.GetX();
                if (Math.Abs(diffX) > Math.Abs(diffY))
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && 
Math.Abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                    {
                        if (diffX > 0)
                        {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && 
Math.Abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if (diffY > 0)
                    {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }


        public override bool OnScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float 
distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnScroll");
            return base.OnScroll (e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

        public override void OnShowPress (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnShowPress");
            base.OnShowPress (e);
        }

        public override bool OnSingleTapConfirmed (MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("OnSingleTapConfirmed");
            return base.OnSingleTapConfirmed (e);
        }

        public void onSwipeRight()
        {
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft()
        {
        }

        public void onSwipeTop()
        {
        }

        public void onSwipeBottom()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What I have to do to get the desired result?

Comment: Please share what you have done so far and do you event to be fired in case the swipe is outside the list boundry

Comment: About sliding conflicts, a demo for us to show your problem will be better.